# Do the number of Sites in a Multi-Site have a practical limit?

Tags: craft3, multi-site

My use case is creating microsites for hundreds to thousands of customers, allowing them to edit/create their own site.  Currently it is set up with channels with auto-created entries for users and no permission to create or edit other's (to mimic a single).  Having similar functionality using Multi-Site
seems nicer so I can use actual singles and allow multiple users to that site.  I noticed when creating multiple sites for testing, that they are all listed on the section page to enable/disable leading me to believe that having hundreds/thousands of Sites enabled is a use-case it was **not** made for.  Are Multi-Sites able to handle thousands of Sites?

Comment: I have same use case here, did you find another suitable solution Chip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd highly discourage this.

We've seen large Craft sites in the half a million to million elements (users, entries, assets, tags, categories, etc.) range. But even those maxed out at 20-30 sites.

Craft's multi-site was designed for sites that share a common information architecture and I'd say even 20-30 sites are pushing what the UI was designed for in the control panel.